# Vb.Net Passing Datagrid view values to Another Open Form

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have two forms. When the users clicks a button on Expenses Form, form2 opens with a datagridview containing records fetched from a database. I want the details of a selected cell to be displayed on different Controls in Expenses form When a row is double clicked. I have tried this with the code below but it doesn't work, as when the cell is double-clicked form2 hides but the datagridview contents are passed to their respective controls in the expense form.Kindly assist.

```
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim dgv As DataGridView
            dgv = dgvbudget

            Expenses.txtid.Text = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
            Expenses.cboseasons.Text = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
            Expenses.dtpexpensedate.Value = CDate(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value)
            Expenses.cboexpenseacc.Text = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value
            Expenses.txtamount.Text = CDbl(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value)
            Me.Hide()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "CMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This isn't a complete example, and you haven't actually specified how it doesn't work.

Comment: The values aren't passed to their respective controls in the expenses form when the datagridview cell is double clicked.

Comment: What event are you using? Is Expenses another form? and if so, is it just the default instance or a new instance of an existing form?

Comment: On the Expenses Form am using the Button_Click Event. Which opens a new instance of different form,form2 but the Expenses form still remains open. On form two , the code is in the cellContentDoubleClick Event.

Comment: are you double clicking the content of the cell? (As in the text that is contained in the cell) that's what triggers CellContentDoubleClick. Whitespace under the mouse won't trigger the event. Perhaps you want that in just CellDoubleClick

Comment: Thanks but still the Data from the datagridview in form2 isn't being passed to the Expense Form controls.

Comment: I think you're going to need to cast the previous form back to its type from the forms collection, but I would need to see how you're instantiating these two forms. (ie, expenses = DirectCast(My.Application.OpenForms("Form1"), Form1)